# How to extract desired data from Jmeter response and to pass it as a request

Tags: jmeter

Am New to JMeter. I have a response as below.

```
{
      "id": "35",
      "rsd": null,
      "col": "green",
      "cc": "B5305F",
      "pn": "KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014",
      "loc": "ABD - MR \/ RS \/ RS",
      "isf": "1",
      "isl": "0",
      "tq": "1",
      "pi": null,
      "st": "1",
      "dsid": "15",
      "cid": "2120",
      "spl": null,
      "wid": "WI\/uo46shpr",
      "inv": null,
      "pdid": "1620",
      "di": "0",
      "pl": "0"
    },
```

Here I need to check if

```
isf=1
isl=0
st=1
```

if so then I have to take the respective `id` and I have to pass it as a request.

I have extracted the isf,isl and st values using regular expression extractor. when I try just to print the values using `Beanshell PostProcessor` as

```
log.info("is_final="+vars.get("${is_final}"));
```

only `null` value passes. Am not getting this. Help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Beanshell statement is a little bit flaky. You either need to use either`vars.get("variableName")`or directly `${variableName}` so if you change your line to:

```
log.info("is_final="+vars.get("is_final"));
```

or

```
log.info("is_final=${is_final}");
```

given `is_final` variable exists and not null you'll see it's value in jmeter.log file.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting.

Comment: Thank for the info. I have the response as follows: {"id":"140","rsd":null,"col":"green","cc":"B5307F","pn":"KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014","loc":"ABD - LR \/ L3 \/ L3","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"15","pi":null,"st":"1","dsid":"15","cid":"2120","spl":null,"wid":"WI\/3ivdfzhg","inv":null,"pdid":"1103","di":"0","pl":"0"} I need to extract the value of iid where isf=1, isl=0, st=1. what is the regular expression that I have to use in regular expression extractor?

Comment: Can u pls look into my new question and provide your suggestion. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/26116584/4049148 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Needed Regular expression for the following

```
if isf=1 and isl=0 and st=1 are true 
extract the id values
```

You have to create the following regex formats to extract the ID values

```
"id":\s"(.+)",\s{7}.+\s{7}.+\s{7}.+\s{7}.+\s{7}.+\s{7}"isf":\s"1".+\s{7}"isl":\s"0".+\s{7}.+\s{7}.+\s{7}"st":\s"1"
```

Note

```
\s - means single space
\s{7} - means seven single spaces
.+ - means any string matches
(.+) - means to extract the id values
```