# how to make jmeter to select unique values from response for each iteration

Tags: jmeter

I have the following response from JMeter:

```
{"tot_cnt":{"tc":"41651","rpp":"100","pdid":"1594"},"mg":[{"id":"683","rsd":"6-May-13 \/ 6-May-13","col":"black","cc":"c_197","pn":"old_NEXUS MARKETING CAMPAIGNS-PERMANENT","loc":"PTD - 07 \/ 18 \/ BX","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"180","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"527","cid":"1917","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/txq8xa56","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"106","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"17670","rsd":"6-Jun-13 \/ 6-Jun-13","col":"black","cc":"c_197","pn":"old_NEXUS MARKETING CAMPAIGNS-PERMANENT","loc":"PTD - 07 \/ 18 \/ BX","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"180","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"527","cid":"1917","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/ckwu5qe8","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"106","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"22","rsd":"22-Jul-13 \/ 22-Jul-13","col":"black","cc":"c_1884","pn":"old_THE ORTHODONTIC CLINC","loc":"15 - 34 \/ 0N \/ RS","isf":"1","isl":"1","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"15","cid":"1992","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/tldj53ky","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1582","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"686","rsd":"29-Jul-13 \/ 29-Jul-13","col":"black","cc":"c_197","pn":"old_NEXUS MARKETING CAMPAIGNS-PERMANENT","loc":"PTD - 07 \/ 18 \/ BX","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"180","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"527","cid":"1917","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/n4olde1g","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"107","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"73","rsd":"5-Aug-13 \/ 5-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_2357","pn":"old_KCA DEATAG","loc":"338 - 34 \/ 0N \/ RS","isf":"1","isl":"1","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"338","cid":"1914","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/zdqbx1zx","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1578","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"137","rsd":"5-Aug-13 \/ 5-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_1219","pn":"old_TYPHOO - J01-TYPHOO- JULY 2013","loc":"56 - 24 \/ 81 \/ L3","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"2","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"56","cid":"2090","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/azdtc77c","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1086","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"70","rsd":"12-Aug-13 \/ 12-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_2394","pn":"old_SKF UK LTD","loc":"338 - 34 \/ 0N \/ RS","isf":"1","isl":"1","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"338","cid":"1914","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/45uzkvp3","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1556","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"1253","rsd":"12-Aug-13 \/ 12-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_2349","pn":"old_JUST TILES","loc":"PTD - 34 \/ 0M \/ MR","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"528","cid":"1955","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/ofunwm5s","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1559","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"1320","rsd":"12-Aug-13 \/ 12-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_2073","pn":"old_NEW COLLEGE SWINDON SUMMER CAMPAIGN","loc":"PTD - 34 \/ 0N \/ RS","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"528","cid":"1955","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/gpp1dejn","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":null,"di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"27","rsd":"19-Aug-13 \/ 19-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_2138","pn":"old_WIRED STUDIO PEAK MEGA REAR","loc":"15 - 34 \/ 0N \/ RS","isf":"1","isl":"1","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"15","cid":"1992","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/b5m0iyuc","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"1597","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null},{"id":"561","rsd":"19-Aug-13 \/ 19-Aug-13","col":"black","cc":"c_3737","pn":"old_LONDON ROAD BRIDGE SCHEME DERBY CITY COUNCIL","loc":"PTD - 83 \/ 4I \/ WB","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"1","pi":"0","st":"2","dsid":"527","cid":"1917","iq":"0","wid":"WI\/1s1xaqxw","inv":null,"rbp":"0","pdid":"2574","di":"0","pl":"0","spl":null}
```

I used `(?=(?:(?!isf).)*?isf":"1)(?=(?:(?!isl).)*?isl":"0)(?=(?:(?!st).)*?st":"2)"id":"(\d+)` regular expression to select the required id.

When I run the test using 5 users, during few tests same id is selected for different iterations causing error.

I need to make jmeter extract some unique values from response for each iteration. 
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want id?with what condition?

Comment: with one thread it is working fine. when I try to run the test with multiple threads say 5, all the five threads are not selecting unique ids. I want the threads to select unique ids for each iteration. How can I do that?

Comment: will the 5 threds be in the same input one after another? or 5 different inputs each being applied regex?

Comment: can you share screenshot of test plan with bit of explanation what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Nachiket Kate:  Am Sorry Kate, I don't have enough reputations to share images :(

Comment: With 5 different inputs each regex will grab ids from each.....  post that..... Then we can find unique

Comment: no reputation is required for adding images, you can add screenshot image to your question from question panel. there is one image icon/button which helps you to add image to question. please do it so that you will get correct answer.

Comment: Which value do you want to get as a result? Please edit your queston and make it bold in the response message from the server. Also you should show the 'template' value in your regex in jmeter. Please extend your question and provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Interim solution:**

In your "Regular Expression Extractor", keep the setting "Match No." as "0"

Even tough the ID's will not be unique but it will randomly select different values rather than selecting same value again & again.

**Complete solution:**

write all the valid "ID" to CSV file in **"1st Thread group"** using Bean Shell Sampler 
& then
In the **"2nd Thread Group"** run the test using created CSV with unique values for each request.

While analyzing the results you can ignore 1st thread group.

Hope this will help.